# ios Controls taking long to get displayed

Tags: ios, view, loading, xib

Not sure if the problem that I am facing is a generic iOS issue or there is some other problem. I have main storyboard file and there are few screens in xib files. The issue is that the controls are taking long to be displayed from xib e.g. if I have a view, then after setting its hidden property as false, it takes few seconds to actually display the view.

Has anybody else faced this issue earlier?

Regards,
Kavita

Comment: Are you calling `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` on the part of the view hierachy you modified?

Comment: No, I'm not using these functions. I'm just playing with their hidden properties.

Comment: So, use them. Does the problem persist?

Comment: I tried using these methods on the superview whose subviews I'm hiding and showing, but I don't see any difference in terms of time. Do you think it'll help if I move these views in the storyboard instead of xib file?

Comment: Try calling them on the actual view's you edited.

Comment: Have tried that as well